# Using Smooch widget with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, smooch

I'm developing a rails app using turbolinks, and I'm trying to get the Smooch widget to work along with turbolinks.

The problem is as turbolinks replaces the body of the page on each page load, the widget I initialized gets removed from the page.

I tried using the embedded mode and setting `data-turbolinks-permanent` like this:

```
Smooch.init({ appToken: token, embedded: true });  
Smooch.render(document.getElementById('smooch-container'));

<div id='smooch-container' data-turbolinks-permanent></div>
```

But it seems that smooch doesn't even insert the widget within this container:

```
<div id="smooch-container" data-turbolinks-permanent=""></div>
<div id="sk-holder">...</div>
```

How can I use components that I need to persist across page loads with turbolinks?

Comment: The Smooch web widget runs on React, which I imagine might get confounded by turbolinks..  so I suspect this won't work without some effort. A quick bit of googling turned up this: https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react you could give that a try.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look at that. I actually managed to render a permanent smooch component, I had to run the render inside a dom load callback. Still, when using the embedded mode there's not styling, and no toggling functionality, so I will maybe just recreate the styling using a react component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to use the private _container variable where the React component is rendered:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function () {
  Smooch._container && $(Smooch._container).detach();
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:render', function () {
    Smooch._container && $('body').append(Smooch._container);
});
```

We append the component to the DOM when a new page is loaded.

Animations will not properly work with this though, so I had to overwrite the CSS animations and use `opacity` to show/hide the component.